# BigQuery standard SQL - run query with table decorators ($ signs)

Tags: sql, decorator, legacy, partition

I'm using BigQuery Standard SQL.

I'm trying to use a "$" decorator on a table in order to refer to a specific partition:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM `raw.events$20161109`
```

And I'm getting the next error:

> Table "raw.events$20161109" cannot include decorator Dismiss

I am able to run the query (bq validation is ok), and the error pops right after I click on "Run Query" button.

When I use the **Legacy SQL**

I have no problem of doing it:

```
SELECT uid 
FROM [raw.events$20161109]
```

Is there any way to run a query using the decorators with Standard SQL ?
I have to do it this way, as a lot of other procedures are based on this decorators format (using the Legacy SQL)

Comment: Not sure what "BigQuery" thinks standard SQL means, but in standard SQL, identifiers with illegal characters need to be quoted with double quotes, e.g.: `"raw.events$20161109"`

Comment: When i try to use a double quote - i can't run the query at all.

Comment: Then that's not "standard SQL"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this time Table Decorators in BigQuery are [only available when using Legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators). There is an open [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35905931) which can be followed to see the progress on bringing this functionality to Standard SQL.